# Generate MacSec traffic via scapy

Tags: scapy

I need to generate MaACsec traffic via scapy, I've tried to follow [scapy.contrib.macsec](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.contrib.macsec.html) .

Here is what i tried:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.inet import Ether
from scapy.contrib.macsec import MACsec
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP
from scapy.all import *

data='test_MACsec'

pkt = Ether(dst="00:00:01:00:00:01", src="00:10:94:00:00:02") / MACsec() / data
sendp(pkt, iface="eth2", count=400)
```

Error I get in wireshark capture:

[image]

Any suggestions about how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: the protocol should be MACsec not its ethertype 0x88e5

Comment: Should be more specific about your "error"

Comment: Looks like you aren't setting any of the MACSec tag fields so what specifically were you expecting to happen for reference to readers/answerers?

You probably need to create an MACSecSA if you want to encrypt(). All you've done above I believe is added the ethertype for macsec and added a default tag

https://fossies.org/linux/privat/scapy-2.4.5.tar.gz/scapy-2.4.5/test/contrib/macsec.uts might help with what you're going for